# AVG Anti-Virus Blocking the TFS 2012 to Function Properly

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using TFS 2012 with 3 user connected via Work Group. The problem is that whenever I disable the AVG(2012) for temporarily, TFS 2012 will work smoothly on all machines. But when I unable AVG and click get a latest  version of a file then visual studio hangs and not respond. How to configure AVG to allow TFS to work. VS 2012 will be hang infinitely until I restart this.

See What VS 2012 in action when it hangs,

[image]

See ProcMon in action at this time,

[image]

Comment: Can you use an exclude on your project directory? http://www.avg.com/ww-en/faq.num-4428  if that fails, try using something like procmon to see what file VS is accessing while it is hung

Comment: Odd, didn't expect the path to be under program files. Where is your workspace located? is it a server or local workspace.

Comment: @Betty, Local WorkSpace. Note, the project is not in Program files. It is inside VS PRojects folder.

Comment: sorry not sure, try contact AVG support?